# How to check if a cron job is running or not through php?

Tags: php, cron

```
#Mins  Hours  Days   Months  Day of the week
10     3      1      1       *       /bin/echo "I don't really like cron"
30     16     *      1,2     *       /bin/echo "I like cron a little"
*      *      *      1-12/2  *       /bin/echo "I really like cron"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the output into a file.

```
*      *      *      1-12/2  *       /bin/echo "I really like cron" >> /var/logs/cron_output.txt
```